# Weird behavior of callback function

Tags: php

I need to parse a parameter string becomes array. Here is the code:

```
$paramStr = 'type,mp3|path,audio/file.php?id=artist01|popup,Yes';

function parse($paramStr) {
    $params = preg_split('#=|,|\|#', $paramStr);
    for ($i=0;$i<count($params);$i+=2) {
        if ($params[$i] == "path") {
            $params[$i+1] = $baseurl . "/" . $params[$i+1];
        }
        $ret[$params[$i]] = $params[$i+1];
    }
    return $ret;
}

if ($paramStr != "") {
    $paramArr = parse($paramStr);
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

When I var_dump($ret), the output is correct:

```
array
  'type' => string 'mp3' (length=3)
  'path' => string 'http://localhost/audio/file.php%3Fid%3Dartist01' (length=49)
  'popup' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
```

However, when I var_dump($paramArr), I got weird output:

```
array
  'type' => string 'mp3' (length=3)
  'path' => string 'http://localhost/audio/file.php?id' (length=34)
  'artist01' => string 'popup' (length=5)
  'Yes' => null
```

Anyone knows why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same `$paramStr` in both cases? In the first case, you have the `=` encoded as `%3D`, the second has a literal `=`. This matters because `=` is one of the delimiter characters in your `preg_split()`.

Comment: Yes. Anyway, I solved by not using callback function, but direct parsing.

Comment: What callback function are you talking about? You're just calling `parse` directly in the question.